Blazor properly updating the UI after an API call
This code does exactly what I want:

Displays a message (div) from the robot saying thinking
Waits for the API call to complete updates that message (div) and scrolls to the message (div)

It feels like this would fail a code review though even though it does exactly what I need.
Is there some better pattern to accomplish this showing the div with "thinking" until the API call is complete.
private async Task SendMessage()
{   
    var messageHolder = userMessage;
    Console.WriteLine($"User Message is: {userMessage}");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messageHolder))
    {
        messages.Add(new ChatMessageInPage { User = "User", Message = messageHolder });
        var msg = new ChatMessageInPage { User = "Robot ", Message = "Thinking..." };
        messages.Add(msg);
        userMessage = string.Empty;
        // THS IS THE ODD CODE
        Task.Run( async () =>
            {
                msg.Message =  await apiRobot.GetBotResponse(messageHolder);
          
                InvokeAsync(() =>
                {
                    NeedScrollBottom = true;
                    StateHasChanged();
                });
            }
        );
        NeedScrollBottom = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}


Normally this should do the same in a simpler and more reliable way:
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messageHolder))
{
    messages.Add(new ChatMessageInPage { User = "User", Message = messageHolder });
    var msg = new ChatMessageInPage { User = "Robot ", Message = "Thinking..." };
    messages.Add(msg);
    userMessage = string.Empty;

    // Simple code - display previous during await
    NeedScrollBottom = true;
    await Task.Delay(1);  // recommended, for when the apiRobot isn't async enough            
    msg.Message =  await apiRobot.GetBotResponse(messageHolder);      
    NeedScrollBottom = true;
}

when this does not work as expected then post the exact results.

Wow! Amazing doing await Task.Delay(1) solved the view issues.  When it is not there it does not update the UI, so I would call it required. Thanks Henk!

It's not always required - it depends on the implementation of GetBotResponse(). I would call it recommended though.

So an example might be if there was a method that did not have an async call available that could cause the async-ness to not be enough?

Yes, your code-path needs to give up the Thread for a moment. Not something you can normally know or require from a Service.
